# Passing a single and a double quote to a python script

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments

I want to start a python script with a single and a double quote like that:

`python app.py '"`

You can start it with a single quote like so:

`python app.py "'"`

Or the same thing reversed with a double quote:

`python app.py '"'`

But I don't know how to do it with both. If I do it like on the start of the question, the interactive Python shell is started. I've also tried escaping the quotes with ^ and \.

Comment: Why would you need that? The use case?

Comment: Please clarify your question. It seems like you are trying to find out if the name can start with quotes? Or are you trying to run it with quotes? It is confusing. Please elaborate.

Comment: I'm trying to run the script with an argument that contains a single and a double quote

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to Python actually, it's your shell that is doing the parsing of arguments and raising errors.

To pass both form of quotes, you need to enclose each with the other:

```
python app.py "'" '"'
```

The first and second will result in single and double quotes, respectively.

---

**Edit:**

To put them both in a single argument:

```
python app.py "'\""
```

Comment: Yes I know that. I'm sorry if my question wasn't so clear, but I want to use both types of quotes in one argument and I haven't figured out a way yet.

Comment: If I do that it puts me directly in the interactive shell

Comment: @UltraMario Which shell are you on? It works for me on `zsh`, `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`.

Comment: Windows PowerShell... I'll probably just continue coding on Linux

Comment: @UltraMario That's wise :)

Comment: @UltraMario Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers